# Passing pointer to an object containing vector to a dll function

Tags: c++, object, dll, vector

I had an idea to create a report printing dialog that could be configurable, e.g. i made a listbox on it, read available reports that are registered in a database. Then, an user could just click on one item in the listbox, click print (let's omit any report parameters for the sake of this question). Adding any new report could be as simple as registering a new dll in the database. All report dlls shoud have a commonly named PrintReport function.

Also, printing should be easy for a programmer writing these dlls. He is given a pointer to an object that he could use for gdiplus drawing.

Here's what i did:

- created said dialog
- created a namespace (PRINTOUT) and some classes in it (one of them is Print, which contains fully initialized Gdiplus::Graphics object and a vector of pointers to metafiles used for print preview)
- created this universal function in the dll which is declared as:

  ```
  extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int PrintReport(PRINTOUT::Print *prn, LONG_PTR ReportData);
  ```
- i then created an object and called the dll library in the following way:

  ```
  typedef BOOL (*tFUNC)(PRINTOUT::Print *, LONG_PTR);
  tFUNC fFUNC=reinterpret_cast<tFUNC>(GetProcAddress(LibInst, "PrintReport"));
  //as a pointer, because i will delete it before unloading a dll. Dll loading code omitted.
  PRINTOUT::Print *prn=new PRINTOUT::Print();
  //this should print using gdiplus object pointer contained in the prn
  //after printing this function just exits
  fFUNC(prn, RpData);
  //cleanup within destructor
  delete prn;
  FreeLibrary(LibInst);
  ```

**THE problem:** Function in a dll has completely different addresses of vectors contained within the *prn* object and i don't understand why. Actually earlier i tried to just declare PRINTOUT::Print prn and pass by reference fFUNC(&prn, RpData) but there was little or no difference. Please try to explain to me why this happens. Address of the *prn* object is the same, but it's innards' addresses are different.

Regards
Kitet

Comment: So all addresses stay the same apart from the stuff in the vector?

Comment: I don't know the answer fully, but here's something that's an interesting read (a few comments down) - http://www.gamedev.net/topic/337108-passing-stdstring-over-dll-boundaries/.  Good luck :)

Comment: @w00te: yep that came to mind immediately. But as he didn't mention that he's using different compiler (settings) I assumed that his instances of std::vector may even be compatible across the DLL boundary

Comment: Yeah, I'd assume you're right too.

Comment: Apart from unneeded linker libraries all compiler settings are the same, target platform defines also.

Comment: @w00te: So, after the lecture - i should basically redesign, since i have so many different types of objects embedded within my PRINTOUT::Print class, from a std::vector to Gdiplus::Graphics and Gdiplus::Metafile... it's bound to break sooner or later, isn't it? Especially because i create a lot of these objects inside the PrintDocument function and delete them in the destructor in the main exe... Actually i started comparing member addresses because i got a heap corruption upon deleting metafiles in the destructor.

Comment: @Kitet hard to follow without seeing your code, but from the sounds of it a redesign's probably right, haha. Chances are if you're confused and debugging random things, the design should be simpler :)

Comment: I think i will try turning the in-dll function into some kind of a callback maybe, so that it draws only and doesn't create anything, maybe returns with a status when e.g. creation of a new page is necessary, letting main exe create any objects it would need, then be re-called and continue on...